# How to watch an array props value changes?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

**Here is my main component.**
I have an array and ı want to send it to my child component to fill necessary fields. I sent it with named infos prop.

```
<template>
    <list-form :infos="infos"/>
</template>
<script>

export default {
   data(){

      return(){
         infos:[
                {name:'',surname:'',date:new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),menu:false},
                {name:'',surname:'',date:new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),menu:false},
                {name:'',surname:'',date:new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),menu:false},
                {name:'',surname:'',date:new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),menu:false}
               ]
      }  
   }
}
</script>
```

**Here is my child component**
I get my prop in here and i used inside v-for loop.

```
<template>
  <v-row v-for="(info,i) in infos" :key="'list-item-'+i">
    
    <v-col cols="6"><v-text-field v-model="info.name"/></v-col>

    <v-col cols="6" > <v-text-field v-model="info.surName"/></v-col>

    <v-col cols="6">
       <v-menu v-model="info.menu"
                            :close-on-content-click="false"
                            transition="scale-transition"
                            offset-y
                            max-width="290px"
                            min-width="auto">

                        <template v-slot:activator="{ on,  attrs }">
                            <v-text-field v-model="info.dateFormatted"
                                          label="date"
                                          placeholder="GG/AA/YYYY"
                                          v-bind="attrs"
                                          v-on="on"/>
                        </template>

                        <v-date-picker
                            v-model="info.date"
                            no-title
                            @input="info.menu = false"
                        />
        </v-menu> 
   </v-col>

  </v-row> 
</template>


export default {
props:{
   infos:{
          type:Array
         }
    }, 
    watch: {
       **//the problem is in here**
         date() {
             this.dateFormatted = this.formatDate(date)
        }, 
    },
    methods: {
        formatDate(date) {
            if (!date) return null
            const [year, month, day] = date.split('-')
            return `${month}/${day}/${year}`
        }
    } 
}
</script>
```

I want to take date changes. If date changed i want to change its format . but I think it has a different way to catch changes in props. I tried some ways for this stuation but ı could not find true way.

Normally ı can get changes inside **watch** but i cant take changes with this way

Comment: Please reformat your code. It's hard to read.

Comment: Firstafall you shouldn't directly use the prop variables in your v-model

Comment: Please refactor your code based on the rules in vue

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to watch prop changes in your child component. Just watch changes in your parent component by using watch (if you really need) and write some conditions in your child component.

When you change data in parent component Vue will update your child component so you don't need to watch it inside.

Comment: In real , i need it inside child componnet because i tried it inside main component already.